# Show Padding-bottom Under Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a div. I have added the style `overflow: auto` to the div - this makes it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9lKS.png)

My question is: how do I add space under the content - like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssONC.png) (as you can see, there's a space under the text - I made this using paint.

**Note: A padding at the bottom when the user has scrolled all the way down is not what I'm asking for.**

My code is:

```
<div class="background" style="overflow: auto;">
<h2>Example</h2>
<p>And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that this was an impossible question

Comment: Heh, welcome to CSS. Things that seem simple in your head or in PhotoShop are sometimes surprisingly difficult to execute. I've updated below with a solution that should get you the effect you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

A cheater method might be just to add a `border-bottom:10px solid white;` to your `.background` div. This would appear outside the scrollbar, however, and doesn't match the comp of what you're trying to achieve.

With substantially more code, however, you can get there; you'll need to add `position:relative;` to the `.background` div, wrap your content in another div and add the following pseudo-element:

```
.background:after {
    background:white; /* Or whatever matches your div */
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:20px;
    width:calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

The width here is meant to be full width minus a set number of pixels for the scrollbar. You'll need to do a lot of crossbrowser testing to figure out the right number to use here, and I also recommend adding some padding to the `.content` div to stop text from peeking through.

Obviously the colors and height can all be adjusted to your layout and preferences.

```css
/* This is only to visually prove the effect and doesn't need to be copied */

body {
  background: violet;
}
.background {
  background: white;
  /* Or whatever matches your layout */
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding:10px;
}
.content:after {
  background: white;
  /* Or whatever matches your layout */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <p>And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much, I wasn't aware that such a 'simple question' would turn out to be this complex!

Comment: Just one question... when the user scrolls down, how do I remove the white space: http://prntscr.com/ajusey

Comment: Looks like you need to add a wrapper div and do some math to account for the scrollbar. I updated my answer with the new code. IMHO, this is all really fussy, and you're better off using the `border-bottom` method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<div class="background" style="overflow: auto; padding-bottom:20px">
<h2>Example</h2>
<p>And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an example And welcome to my profile! This is an exampleAnd welcome to my profile! This is an example</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That adds the padding when the user scrolls to the bottom. As I previously requested, I need it like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssONC.png